# Find average of numbers in a column when the value of a number changes in a different column using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file which looks like :

```
      7 8108 1571 7769 4.34 96.19 NaN 186.07
      7 8108 1571 7770 4.28 99.11 NaN 190.88
      7 8108 1571 7771 2.26 102.85 NaN 196.68
      7 8108 1571 7772 3.47 102.92 NaN 198.78
      7 8108 1571 7773 3.52 105.92 NaN 210.46
      7 8108 1571 7774 4.99 103.15 NaN 211.16
      7 8108 1571 7775 5.80 101.74 NaN 215.09
      7 8108 1571 7776 3.44 101.13 NaN 213.64
      7 8107 1571 1 24.20 3049.37 47.74 201.60
      7 8107 1571 2 25.43 3197.89 41.10 203.77
      7 8107 1571 3 20.39 3204.50 58.53 201.34
      7 8107 1571 4 29.77 3237.13 59.81 189.35
      7 8107 1571 5 25.15 3101.98 61.84 174.00
      7 8107 1571 6 28.57 3478.38 69.62 180.99
      7 8107 1571 7 27.33 3313.49 62.96 164.91
      7 8107 1571 8 25.20 3447.72 56.84 166.96
      7 8107 1571 9 21.74 3613.38 60.16 170.33
```

I want to calculate the average of all the values in column five whenever the value changes in column 2 and then print out all the averaged values in column 5 five for each value in column 2 .

Please help.

Comment: What have you so far?

Comment: Are you sure your data is always sorted on column 2?

Comment: I am curious why you are using `awk` here. Sure, this can be solved by `awk`, but this is better problem for `SQL`. `select column2,avg(column5) from table group by column2` is all you need to do this in `SQL` if you load your file into an RDBMS of your choice.

Comment: @toddlermenot *if you load your file into an RDBMS*. How many lines to create the table, import the file, run the query and drop the table? That type of processing is precisely why awk was designed in the first place.

Comment: @Matthieu: 3 more lines I guess.  I am NOT against using `AWK`, just felt coding this problem as a more natural thing to do in `SQL`. IMO, from a standpoint of readability, the `SQL` solution would fare better than `AWK`. One glance you would know what the SQL does (due to it being declarative). Unless you are already well-versed in AWK, you'll need a minute to understand what is going on. Maybe it is just me. To each his own. *shrug*

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{s[$2]+=$5; n[$2]++;} END{for (k in s) print k,s[k]/n[k];}' file
8107 25.3089
8108 4.0125
```

#### How it works

The code uses two associative arrays.  `s` contains the sums of column 5 for each value of column 2.  `n` contains the number of times each column 2 appeared.

- `s[$2]+=$5; n[$2]++`

  For this value of column 2, add column 5 to the sums `s` and add one to the line count, `n`.
- `END{for (k in s) print k, s[k]/n[k];}`

  When we reach the end of the file, then loop through each value `k` of column 2 that we saw and print out the average, `s[k]/n[k]`.

#### Sorting the output

To sort the output numerically by the first column of output (which was column 2 of input):

```
$ awk '{s[$2]+=$5; n[$2]++;} END{for (k in s) print k,s[k]/n[k];}' file | sort -n
8107 25.3089
8108 4.0125
```

To sort numerically by the average value:

```
$ awk '{s[$2]+=$5; n[$2]++;} END{for (k in s) print k,s[k]/n[k];}' file | sort -nk2
8108 4.0125
8107 25.3089
```

Comment: There is just one issue that the output that I am getting is not sorted in either increment or decrements it's completely random , is there any way I can sort out the output in the same order of increment as of column 2 , thanks a lot.

Comment: What OS are you on?  (Alternatively, what version of awk are you using?)

Comment: @AbhishakeYadav I added a section on sorting the output.

Answer (score 0):

This holds in array `tot` indexed by column 2 the totals,
and in `num` the count.

```
awk '{ tot[$2] += $5; num[$2]++ }
END{ for(i in tot)printf "%s %s\n",i,tot[i]/num[i] }'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
$2!=prev { if (cnt) print prev, sum/cnt; sum=cnt=0 }
{ sum+=$5; cnt++; prev=$2 }
END { if (cnt) print prev, sum/cnt }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
8108 4.0125
8107 25.3089
```